# Can't get my SQL server to work with Excel 2013

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel

I want to view my database and tables in the Excel.

So I have my SQL server all set up (it shows on the SQL workbench that the server is "Running").
However, when I try to connect to my SQL server through Excel Power Query, after typing down my server ip it gives me an error, "Unable to connect" (provider:Names Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL server).

I have tried googling and I couldn't find something relevant. I mean it says that the server is clearly running at the SQL workbench, also, most of the answers I found are outdated.

**I am running Windows 7 64 bit, Excel 2013, SQL server 5.7**

**UPDATE**

I have installed Visual Studio Tools for Office, so that I can install 'MySQL for Excel' Add-in.
When I did I could connect to my database and export it to Excel! :)

Thank you everyone for trying to help! You are AWESOME :D

Comment: mysql and ms sql are two different products. Pls remove the unnecessary product tag!

Comment: What is SQL Server 5.7?  If such a thing even existed, it hasn't been supported for over 15 years.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is the current version so I assume that is what they have. I have no idea if excel can connect to a MySQL database.

Comment: Looks like he is trying to connect to a MySQL using SQL server connection according to the error message. Itai, can you elaborate on how to get to the error you are seeing?

Comment: @mauroneto 
Yes. I go to Excel 2013, "POWER QUERY" tab, "From Database" selecting From SQL Server Database. Then a window opens "SQL Server Database - Import data from a SQL Server database", and it asks me to type down a Server, I type down my server:127.0.0.1
then either I get the error "Unable to Connect" bla bla bla and what I wrote. **OR** another window opens, asking me for either my windows credentials or I can choose database credentials, I get a "Internal connection fatal error" or the same error I told you about.